# Can't read out the Item I get by ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I can't read out the subject of the Item which is provided by the Event

```
ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(object Item)
```

I tried to convert this Item to an Outlook.MailItem how it's described on StackOverflow and other sites. But I can't cast it because it's not of type MailItem. But which type is it? If I make a quick watch on it, I can see all the properties like Subject and so on. So the Item object has to be a MailItem.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders["TFS Notifications"].Items.ItemAdd += new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(TfsNotificationsFolderAdd);
    }

private void TfsNotificationsFolderAdd(object Item)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem;

        if ((mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem) != null && PlugInActionscs.GetFileChangeCount(mailItem) >= 10)
            mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
    }
```

Comment: What does "I can't read out the subject" mean? Do you get an error? Your code below does not attempt to read the Subject property.

Comment: Reading the subject is in an underlaying function of PlugInActions.GetFileChangeCount(Outlook.MailItem). But that does not matter. The big problem is, how described in the second part, that I can’t cast the “object Item” parameter to something which I can work with like Outlook.MailItem. Even reflection doesn’t work to get the subject property. But if I make a quick watch into this Item object in Visual Studio, I can see the property “subject” which is the subject of the mailItem and I need this value.

Comment: So if you change the first line to "Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem", you get back null?

Comment: Item as Outlook.MailItem is null, yes.